# How to use ActiveForm instance across Ajax requests in Yii 2?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii, yii2

For example we have this `ActiveForm` implementation in a sample view:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?=$form->field($model, 'first_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]); ?>

    <?=$form->field($model, 'last_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]); ?>

    <div id="additional-form-fields"></div>

    <a href="#" id="load-additional-form-fields">
        Load more fields
    </a>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Now, I want to add more `ActiveField` / `ActiveForm` fields inside this form and place them in the `#additional-form-fields` element with Ajax, I'd do a simple `jQuery` callback:

```
$('#load-additional-form-fields').click(function() {
    $.get('/site/additional-fields', {}, function(data) {
        $('#additional-form-fields').html( data );
    });
});
```

And the action `additional-fields` inside `SiteController` would be something as:

```
public function actionAdditionalFields() {
    $model = new User;

    return $this->renderAjax('additional-fields', [
        'model' => $model,
        // I could pass a 'form' => new ActiveForm, here, but it's a big NO-NO!
    ]);
}
```

And this works perfectly, only if I don't use any other `ActiveField` fields inside this action's view:

```
<?=$form->field($model, 'biography')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]); ?>

<?=$form->field($model, 'country')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]); ?>

<?=$form->field($model, 'occupation')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]); ?>
```

Of course, I have to pass or instatiate `$form` somehow in this view, but it's NOT an option to use another `ActiveForm::begin()` / `ActiveForm::end()` anywhere inside this view since it will create another `<form>` tag and thus when I inject the Ajax response, I'll end up with with a `<form>` inside a `<form>` ...

Now, my question is as follows: Since I want to use `ActiveForm`, how can I share an instance of the `ActiveForm` through out multiple requests?

Is it doable / possible, if so, please help me realize how?

So far I have tried to put `$form` inside a session, but that's definitelly not working and not an option. Different than that, I've tried when passing parameters to `renderAjax`:

```
[
    'model' => $model,
    'form' => new ActiveForm,
]
```

In this case I get the following:

1. Form fields are created as they should with appopriate names and id's.
2. jQuery is loaded again (at the bottom of the response: `<script src="...">` ... you get the idea)
3. I don't get the generated JavaScript for validation.

Is there anyway to share an instance of `$form`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have manage to do this, so I'll post the solution here and I'll open an issue on Github - might be useful in future versions.

#### 1. Updates in `yii2\widgets\ActiveForm.php`

I've added a following property to the `ActiveForm` class:

```
/**
 * @var boolean whether to echo the form tag or not
 */
public $withFormTag = true;
```

And I've changed `run()` method into this (check for `// <-- added`):

```
public function run()
{
    if (!empty($this->_fields)) {
        throw new InvalidCallException('Each beginField() should have a matching endField() call.');
    }

    $content = ob_get_clean();

    if($this->withFormTag) { // <-- added
        echo Html::beginForm($this->action, $this->method, $this->options);
    } // <-- added

    echo $content;

    if ($this->enableClientScript) {
        $id = $this->options['id'];
        $options = Json::htmlEncode($this->getClientOptions());
        $attributes = Json::htmlEncode($this->attributes);
        $view = $this->getView();
        ActiveFormAsset::register($view);
        $view->registerJs("jQuery('#$id').yiiActiveForm($attributes, $options);");
    }

    if($this->withFormTag) { // <-- added
        echo Html::endForm();
    } // <-- added
}
```

Thus if we instantiate a form like this:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'withFormTag' => false,
]);
```

It will not `echo` a `<form>` tag, but will render all `ActiveField` items and it will create their respective JavaScript/jQuery validators if `$this->enableClientScript = true;`.

#### 2. Updates in my local view/file

After applying the previous fix in the base class, I needed to do the following in my view:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'withFormTag' => false,
    'id' => 'w0',
]); ?>
```

I had to pass the `id` parameter since every next instance of the ActiveForm class is incremented by `1`, and I want my JavaScript/jQuery validators to be applied to the parent form, which by default starts from `0` -> `w0`.

And this is what did the trick!

Here's the Github issue as well: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/12973